# Export pfx certificate after approving pending request

Tags: certificate, ad-certificate-services

In Active Directory Certificate Authority I have template with **CA certificate manager approval**.

[CA picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayX5m.jpg)

When I approve a request I can not export issued certificates to pfx format. How can I export them?

Without **CA certificate manager approval** I can do this using Certificate (Local Computer) mmc snap-in.